# ExtJS 4: cloning stores

Tags: javascript, extjs, model, extjs4, store

I'm trying to figure out how to clone an `Ext.data.Store` without keeping the old reference.

Let me explain better with some code. Here's the source store:

```
var source = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age'] ,
    data: [
        {name: 'foo', age: 20} ,
        {name: 'boo', age: 30} ,
        {name: 'too', age: 10} ,
        {name: 'yoo', age: 80} ,
        {name: 'zoo', age: 30}
    ]
});
```

Follows an example of what I want to do:

```
var target = source;
target.removeAll ();
// Here I need to have target empty and source unchanged
// But in this case, source is empty as well
```

Now, in the above example the copy is done by reference while I need to do it by value.
So I found `Ext.clone ()` in the docs but it seems it doesn't work for complex object, like `Ext.data.Store`:

```
var target = Ext.clone (source);
target.removeAll ();
// source is still empty
```

Then I tried with `Ext.data.Model.copy ()` but the only way to do it work is this:

```
var target = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age']
});

source.each (function (model) {
    target.add (model.copy ());
});
```

Now, for my reasons, I don't want to instantiate another `Ext.data.Store`, so I want to avoid this:

```
var target = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age']
});
```

I'd like to have something like this:

```
var target;

source.each (function (model) {
    target.add (model.copy ());
});
```

But, obviously, it doesn't work.

**So, how can I clone the source store?**

Comment: I don't think there is a way to copy a store. Instantiating a new, empty one is probably the only choice you have.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you want to clone your store?

Comment: Because I need to represent some data into a grid. I'm using MVC and a complex model associations for a complex nested XML database. I'm searching for something different from defining a new store, obviously if it's possible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**ExtJS 3.x solution**

Try this:

```
cloneStore : function(originStore, newStore) {

    if (!newStore) {
        newStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model : originStore.model
        });
    } else {
        newStore.removeAll(true);
    }

    var records = [], originRecords = originStore.getRange(), i, newRecordData;
    for (i = 0; i < originRecords.length; i++) {
        newRecordData = Ext.ux.clone(originRecords[i].copy().data);
        newStore.add(new newStore.model(newRecordData, newRecordData.id));
    }

    newStore.fireEvent('load', newStore);

    return newStore;
}
```

Note: `Ext.ux.clone` is a separated plugin (you will find it) which makes a *deep* clone of an object. Maybe, Ext JS 4 provides a familiar thing, I don't know.. I'm using this special clone since Ext JS 3.x

It is possible that it is required to specify the proxy `memory`when creating a new store (I'm not sure right now because I'm using always the "provided" way.

**ExtJS 4.x solution**

```
function deepCloneStore (source) {
    var target = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: source.model
    });

    Ext.each (source.getRange (), function (record) {
        var newRecordData = Ext.clone (record.copy().data);
        var model = new source.model (newRecordData, newRecordData.id);

        target.add (model);
    });

    return target;
}
```

Comment: As Yoshi said, maybe that's the only way to do it.
So, that's exactly what I was looking for! I added the ExtJS4 solution to your answer! Thanks a lot knalli!

Comment: These methods do not copy any relations (stores) the records may have in turn, so not deep enough for models with relations.

Comment: Well, this means that the relation data aren't stored into `data`. More "deeper" is not possible. ;)

Comment: the ExtJS 4 solution does not copy any relationships as pcguru already said!

Comment: just use 

target.add(record.copy())

you dont need that extra code above that line.

Comment: No, that is not correct. Referring latest 4.x branch spec http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-copy, you will see this approach will not clone a record but duplicate (copy with new id). That is not the same.

Comment: Do you have something for EXTJS 5?

Comment: @oneofakind Check my answer for an ExtJS 5 and 6 version

Answer (score 15):

**ExtJS 6.x, 5.x and 4.x solution**

Here's a quasi-all ExtJS versions solution. Mind you that record.copy already creates a clone of the data. No need to Ext.clone that again.

```
function deepCloneStore (source) {
    source = Ext.isString(source) ? Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(source) : source;

    var target = Ext.create(source.$className, {
        model: source.model,
    });

    target.add(Ext.Array.map(source.getRange(), function (record) {
        return record.copy();
    }));

    return target;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this and see how it goes

Comment: That's much tidier. Works fine in ExtJS4 if you change "source.getModel()" to "source.model".
I also added this line at the start, to give the option of supplying a store ID:
source = Ext.isString(source) ? Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(source) : source;

Comment: For Ext 6.5 and 7 I would use record.clone() instead of record.copy(). States like `dropped`, `phantom` and `dirty` are kept.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following successfully in Ext.js 4.1:

```
var source = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age'],
    data: [
        {name: 'foo', age: 20},
        {name: 'boo', age: 30},
    ],
});
```

In a method:

```
cloneStore: function (source) {
    var clone = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['name', 'age']
    });

    // load source store data
    clone.loadData(source.data.items);

    return clone;
}
```

Inline:

```
var clone = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['name', 'age']
}).loadData(source.data.items);
```

Answer (score 0):

since this is still something I was looking for and the above answers did not fix it for me, I found another solution myself:

```
var target = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
    // add other properties here if needed
    reader: source.reader
})
```

This worked for me to create clones of a store.