# Ext js store has Many copy to another store

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have data store "a" with hasMany attribute,trying to create new store "b" by copying hasMany records of "a" with below code,but when i use b store for combo box it throws error saying record.length is undefined

```
var b = Ext.create("Ext.data.store"{
model:'service'});
Ext.getStore("a").each(function(record,id){
for(var i in record){
b.add(record.raw.subservice);
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, try this. I hope it helps.

```
function deepCloneStore (source) {
    var target = Ext.create ('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: source.model
    });
    Ext.each (source.getRange (), function (record) {
        var newRecordData = Ext.clone (record.copy().data);
        var model = new source.model (newRecordData, newRecordData.id);
        target.add (model);
    });
    return target;
}
```

Original [source code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12647736/1326692).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate store, instead you need to iterate `store.data.items`.
And you do not need `for cycle` for record.
Try this

```
var b = Ext.create("Ext.data.store"{
    model:'service'
});
Ext.getStore("a").data.items.each(function(record,id){
    //You can add multiple records by calling .add method once
    b.add(record.data.subServiceItems);
});
```

Write if this does not help.